# HTML Размер изображения деформирован

Tags: html, html5, xhtml

Здраствуйте. Странный размер изображения-ссылки при просмотре. Изображения-ссылки вырезаны на прозрачном фоне psd-макета и сохранены в формате PNG-24. При выведении на страницу у каждого изображения-ссылки появилась разная ширина. margin , padding по нулям(фотография). В чем может быть причина? Стоит для каждого устанавливать ширину???
Спасибо за помощь :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это ширина ячейки, а не изображения. Размер ячеек зависим от родительской таблицы и её представления, так что нельзя изменить размер одной ячейки - это бесполезно.

Comment: Other, Может стоит добавить изображения-ссылки в отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Как будто другая таблица будет себя иначе вести. Эти изображения лучше вообще без таблицы выводить, просто с обтеканием побаловаться.

Comment: Other, я понял, спасибо)